# Can you move a Major Image to where you can't see it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

The [*major image*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image) spell states:

> **Range:** 120 feet
>
> [...]
>
> You create the image of an object a creature or some other visible phenomenon that is no larger than a 20-foot cube. The image appears at a spot that you can see within range and lasts for the duration.
>
> [...]
>
> As long as you are within range of the illusion you can use your action to cause the image to move to any other spot within range.

A spellcaster casts *major image*. **Can they move the illusion created by *major image* out of their sight?** Does the answer change depending on whether "out of sight" means "behind total cover" or "heavily obscured but not behind total cover"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes,** 
following the principle that spells only do what they say they do.

The only stipulation the spell description gives is that the area you move the image to be in range. If there was a restriction that the caster can only move the image to a visible area it would be stated be specifically.

In fact,  it specifically states you can move it to "any other spot within range."

Comment: However, the caster should "spy" on the image somehow, else he won't be able to make it act andd react appropriately to fool onlookers. Say, caster hear some enemy soldiers in other room and makes an illusion of their leader go into that room and give them "new orders". There might be furniture in the room and thus the illusion might walk right through obstacles. If the interaction is far enough, caster might not hear the soldiers aanswering their "leader", and thus could make the illusion say wrong things with wrong timing / reactions. Thus enemies could more easily detect it's an illusion.